# How to assign directory permissions to administrator for a particular directory?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissions, .net-4.5

I am trying to assigning permissions only to administrators and denying access to other non-admin users. Below is the code-

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\C00");

DirectorySecurity dirSec = di.GetAccessControl();
dirSec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);

SecurityIdentifier systemSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);
NTAccount systemAccount = (NTAccount)systemSid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

SecurityIdentifier adminSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
NTAccount adminAccount = (NTAccount)adminSid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

SecurityIdentifier userSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
NTAccount userAccount = (NTAccount)userSid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

//access rule 1
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(systemAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
//access rule 2
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(adminAccount, FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
//access rule 3
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(userAccount, FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny));
            di.SetAccessControl(dirSec);
return;
```

With the above code in place, even the administrator is not able to access the folder but without the access rule denoted in the comment as "access rule 3" it works as expected.Can anybody make this clear for me to why this is happening?

Comment: The 'deny' type has higher priority than 'allow'. Therefore if 'George' is 'user' and 'administrator' and users have 'deny', then even 'George' can not access the folder.

Comment: Yeah..that makes sense.Then how can I achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following illustration to better understand how works DACL

[image: DACL can allow access to one thread while denying access to another]

Windows stops checking access control entries when the requested access is explicitly granted or denied. Order of ACEs is very important. Note that if the ACE order were different in the example, the system might have granted access to Thread A.

Some notes about deny ACE

> In most cases, you can control access to an object by using
>   access-allowed ACEs; you do not need to explicitly deny access to an
>   object. The exception is when an ACE allows access to a group and you
>   want to deny access to a member of the group. To do this, place an
>   access-denied ACE for the user in the DACL ahead of the access-allowed
>   ACE for the group. Note that the order of the ACEs is important
>   because the system reads the ACEs in sequence until access is granted
>   or denied. The user's access-denied ACE must appear first; otherwise,
>   when the system reads the group's access allowed ACE, it will grant
>   access to the restricted user.

[How AccessCheck Works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/aa446683(v=vs.85).aspx)

[How the System Uses ACLs](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-acl-use.htm)

Comment: One doubt though.If a directory contains 3 different subfolders,can I give different permissions to them?

Comment: Absolutely. Every object (folder or file) can have own access control list.